# Do VIEW ANY DEFINITION, VIEW ANY DATABASE, VIEW SERVER STATE allow to SELECT from any sys and dm view/function?

Tags: sql-server, database, permissions

I've a user with 3 permissions

```
VIEW ANY DEFINITION
VIEW ANY DATABASE
VIEW SERVER STATE
```

Do these permissions allow to select(and select only) from any sys table, dynamic management view/function?
In Microsoft docs it stated that:

```
To query a dynamic management view or function requires SELECT permission on object and VIEW SERVER STATE or VIEW DATABASE STATE permission.
```

Is the VIEW ANY DATABASE inherited from `public` role equivalent to the VIEW DATABASE STATE permission?

Also from where does this user get the above-mentioned SELECT permission on dynamic-management views? I didn't find any dm that i cannot select from, are there some that need explicit `GRANT SELECT`?

SqlServer version: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)

Comment: FYI, I really recommend updating your install; there were multiple bugs in the RTM version of SQL Server 2019. There have since been 2 years of updates. You've also *never* installed a security update on the instance either.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm a bit surprised that dev version on [official website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) isn't equipped with security updates.

Comment: Because after you install the service you need to decide if you want to go down the GDR update path of the CU update path; and to do that you need to start at RTM. With prior versions of SQL Server you would download the latest SP, however, SPs don't exist on SQL Server any more.

Answer (score 0):

You should test this out yourself.  Use the EXECUTE AS command to see exactly what the login can or cannot do.

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'other_user';  
SELECT * FROM your_db.dbo.your_table
REVERT
```

See if you get a result, or a permissions error.